# How to combine two queries with case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count, pivot

How to combine two queries with case statement

query1

```
SELECT   DATE(created_at),COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count1 
FROM     user
WHERE    by_user = '3'  
AND      DATE(created_at) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE-2 AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

query2

```
SELECT   DATE(created_at),COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count2 
FROM     USER  
WHERE    by_user <> '3'  
AND      DATE(created_at) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE-2 AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

Expected output:

```
+---------------------+--------+--------+
| date(created_at)    | count1 | count2 |
+---------------------+--------+--------+
| 30/12/2019,12:00 AM | 4000   | 5000   |
| 29/12/2019,12:00 AM | 2434   | 5432   |
+---------------------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select date(created_at), 
  count(distinct case when by_user = '3' then user_id end) as count1, 
  count(distinct case when by_user <> '3' then user_id end) as count2 
from user  
where date(created_at) between current_date-2 and current_date
group by date(created_at)
```

The conditions `where  by_user = '3'` or `where  by_user <> '3'` are checked with a `CASE` expression, so they are removed from the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    date(created_at) day_at,
    count(distinct case when by_user = 3 then user_id end) as count1, 
    count(distinct case when by_user <> 3 then user_id end) as count2 
from user  
where 
    created_at >= current_date - interval 2 day 
    and created_at < current_date + interval 1 day
group by day_at
order by day_at
```

Notes:

- if column `by_user` is of a numeric data type, you want to do numeric comparison, not strings comparison
- I would suggest not applying date functions to `created_at` when filtering, and using half-open intervals instead (this is an index-friendly strategy). I changed your `where` clause accordingly, and also modified your date arithmetics to use the standard `interval` syntax.